# Lock в операционной системе

Tags: linux, многопоточность, unix, процесс

Прочел про команду LOCK# для процессора архитектуры x86, которая блокирует шину памяти на время выполнения команды следующей.
Возник такой вопрос, насколько я знаю для реализации локов процессов используется схема примерно следующая: поставить лок на изменение адреса памяти какого-то (не очень понимаю как это происходит более детально), выполнить изменения, снять лок.

Вопросы следующие:

- Что происходит когда процесс/поток говорит что хочет залочить изменение блока адресов, например 1024-1040? Бит какой-то выставляется где-то или что? (Рассматривается многоядерная система и какой-то общий кусок памяти)
- Что будет если процесс залочил изменение памяти, а после отвалился? Снимает ли ОС лок или что?

UPD: То есть в моем понимании раз мы можем атомарно изменить значение с 0 до 1, то это позволяет нам где-то вести инфу о том, что процесс 1 вошел в критическую область, но ему же нужно после этого допустим 100500 операций выполнить и после этого выйти из критической области, но где хранится информация какие адреса в памяти он собирается изменять (его критическая область) в результате этих 100500 операций? Или тупо просто каждая команда с LOCK# выполняется до релиза?

Если всё вверху звучит как бред, объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает на самом деле. :)

Comment: Назвались Эллочкой — отыгрывайте хотя бы женский пол :)

Comment: Для возможно пожелающих ответить -- основное тут: `"объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает на самом деле"`.

Comment: @avp, если знаете ответ, не стесняйтесь, высказывайтесь :)

Comment: Вас интересует локинг именно *внутри ядра* (на самом нижнем уровне сильно зависит от архитектуры) или в user level? В любом случае лучший ответ в сорсах.

Comment: @avp, да, как раз внутри ядра, мне достаточно примера для какой-то одной архитектуры, к примеру там блокируется шина памяти (хотя как мне сказали - это уже прошлый век), выставляется бит в какой-то структуре ядра что страница общей памяти или область залочена и при попытке записать в нее что-то другим процессом он приостанавливается и вносится в список ожидающих, как-то так я это себе представляю, но хотелось бы чуточку подробнее :)

Comment: В первом приближении есть 2 уровня блокировок -- активная (spinlock) -- циклически опрашиваем бит в обусловленном (для этого ресурса) месте (про BTS Вам уже сказали) и блокировка с уходом в диспетчер. Во втором случае смотрим на ресурс (опять битик где-то) и если он занят, то записываем себя в очередь к ресурсу, отмечаем себя (в TCB) как ждущего и вызываем scheduler. Когда процесс, владеющий ресурсом будет его освобождать, он снимет наше ожидание (в нашем TCB) и выкинет нас из очереди к ресурсу. Когда-нибудь sсheduler увидит, что мы активны и вернет нам управление... Коротеньнко, как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

> UPD: То есть в моем понимании раз мы можем атомарно изменить значение
>   с 0 до 1, то это позволяет нам где-то вести инфу о том, что процесс 1
>   вошел в критическую область, но ему же нужно после этого допустим
>   100500 операций выполнить и после этого выйти из критической области,
>   но где хранится информация какие адреса в памяти он собирается
>   изменять (его критическая область) в результате этих 100500 операций?
>   Или тупо просто каждая команда с LOCK# выполняется до релиза?

Нет необходимости где-то хранить адреса памяти, это забота программиста, использовать элементы синхронизации потоков/процессов во время обращения к разделяемой области памяти. Если логика программы подразумевает несколько таких областей, для каждой предусматривается свой элемент(ы) синхронизации.

UPD: Выполнение префикса [LOCK](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/LOCK) совместно с операцией (для примера) [BTS - Проверка и установка бита](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/BTS), при некоторых оговорках, позволяют создать простейший элемент межпроцессорной синхронизации.

Comment: вопрос как раз в том как работает примитив синхронизации на уровне `код примитива - операция на процессоре (ядрах) - внутренние структуры операционной системы`
пример: 2 процесса на разных ядрах, каждый пытается изменить общий кусок памяти; что, где, куда, когда? :)
спасибо!

Comment: короче говоря, как это разрулила операционная система у себя под капотом? команды, что где хранит, взаимодействие ядер и тп )

Comment: @EllochkaCannibal, в смысле управления памятью внутри ядра речь всегда идет о страницах. Локируются дескрипторы физических страниц (есть такая структура данных в ядре), участвующих в некой операции. А к процессу, конечно, есть привязка, и при exit они разблокируются вместе с освобождением других ресурсов, приписанных к процессу.

Answer (score 1):

Нигде ничего не хранится. Если один поток обращается к памяти, находясь в критической области - второй поток может обращаться к той же самой области памяти, находясь снаружи критической области.

Кстати, само понятие "критическая секция" означает не защищенную область памяти - а участок программы, в котором не могут находиться два потока одновременно.